# Vertx WebClient reponds slowly

Tags: java, rx-java2, vert.x, vertx-verticle, vertx-httpclient

I am new to vertx and RxJava. I am trying to implement a simple test program. However, I am not able to understand the dynamics of this program. Why do some requests take more than 10 seconds to respond?

Below is my sample Test application

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx);

Observable < Object > google = hitURL("www.google.com", webClient);
Observable < Object > yahoo = hitURL("www.yahoo.com", webClient);

for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  google.repeat(100).subscribe(timeTaken -> {
    if ((Long) timeTaken > 10000) {
      System.out.println(timeTaken);
    }
  }, error -> {
    System.out.println(error.getMessage());
  });
  yahoo.repeat(100).subscribe(timeTaken -> {
    if ((Long) timeTaken > 10000) {
      System.out.println(timeTaken);
    }
  }, error -> {
    System.out.println(error.getMessage());
  });
}
}

public static Observable < Object > hitURL(String url, WebClient webClient) {
return Observable.create(emitter -> {
  Long l1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
  webClient.get(80, url, "").send(ar -> {
    if (ar.succeeded()) {
      Long elapsedTime = (System.currentTimeMillis() - l1);
      emitter.onNext(elapsedTime);
    } else {
      emitter.onError(ar.cause());
    }
    emitter.onComplete();
  });
});
}
}
```

What I want to know is, what is making my response time slow?

Answer (score 5):

The problem here seems to be in the way you are using `WebClient` and/or the way you are measuring "response" times (depending on what you are trying to achieve here).

Vert.x's `WebClient`, like most http clients, under the hood uses limited-size connection pool to send the requests. In other words, calling `.send(...)` does not necessarily start the http request immediately - instead, it might wait in some sort of queue for an available connection. Your measurements include this potential waiting time.

You are using the default pool size, which seems to be 5 (at least in the latest version of Vert.x - it's defined [here](https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/http/HttpClientOptions.java#L38)), and almost immediately starting 200 http requests. It's not surprising that most of the time your requests wait for the available connection.

You might try increasing the pool size if you want to test if I'm right:

> WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, new WebClientOptions().setMaxPoolSize(...));

Comment: What is the right configurable pool size for my instance? any idea on how to calculate it per core?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy answer to that. There are simply too many factors at play, so the proper size will be application dependent. You can google some resources on proper sizing of connection pools (most of them, however, talk about database connections, which usually are a bit different than http connections), but probably the most reliable way to find the proper size is through performance tests.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Very helpful.